# SVG header cropping a bitmap - but with responsiviness

Tags: html, css, svg, bitmap

I´m trying to create a header in a website with the following effect:
[image: Example]

My idea is to keep the center of the Example image in smaller screens (the red guides indicate this screen side). Besides this, the bitmap would vanish on the side borders like a gradient.

Any help in how to accomplish this using HTML, SVG and CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following a different approach to achieve the same result.
Instead of trying to crop the image, I created a white wave and used it over the image.

Here is small working code (it´s in React but it is simple to see the CSS/HTML parts):
https://codesandbox.io/s/header-cropped-vnlr0